# Create Mysql Trigger before Insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, adminer

i've tried to make an MYSQL Trigger on Adminer, but it doesn't work.
Here is my Code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER handle100kRows BEFORE INSERT ON `4013834123456`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `4013834123456`) = "100000" THEN BEGIN
        DELETE FROM 4013834123456 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
    END
    END IF

END;
```

Following errors appear:(1064): (1064): Syntax error near '4013834123456 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 END END IF END' at line 6

Ive just tried it with ; on the END's but then appears more errors...
I work with Adminer 4.1.0 an MySQL Database!
Thx for help!

UPDATE, now it works, with delimiter:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER handle100kRows BEFORE INSERT ON `4013834123456`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `4013834123456`) = "100000" THEN
        DELETE FROM `4013834123456` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END;
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the escape the table name `4013834123456` with backticks.

Also you have and `end` too much.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER handle100kRows BEFORE INSERT ON `4013834123456`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `4013834123456`) = "100000" THEN
        DELETE FROM `4013834123456` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Ok i escaped it like this: DELETE FROM `4013834123456` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1    -> NOW:  (1064): Syntax error near 'END END IF END' at line 7  ( ` not shown )

Comment: I think semicolon is missing at the end of END & ENDIF

Comment: Now:  CREATE TRIGGER handle100kRows BEFORE INSERT ON `4013834123456`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `4013834123456`) = "100000" THEN
        DELETE FROM `4013834123456` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END; appears: (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 5  and (1064): Syntax error near 'END IF' at line 1